SpringSecurity 6.3.3 custom webfilter use example?
I had some trouble using spring webflux with spring security. Here is my version list:

spring-boot-starter-webflux 3.3.4
spring-security-web 6.3.3
Java 21

I configured a JwtValidationWebFilter, the code is as follows:
@Component
public class JwtValidationWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        String token = extractToken(exchange.getRequest());

        if (!StringUtils.hasText(token)) {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }

        LogUtils.info("从请求头中提取 token: {}", token);
        boolean validated = jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token);
        if (!validated) {
            LogUtils.info("验证 token 失败");
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
        Authentication authentication = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
        try {
            LogUtils.info("提取的权限节点: {}", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authentication.getAuthorities()));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // 设置上下文
        Context context = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication) ;
        return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(context) ;
    }

    private String extractToken(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

And I configured SecurityConfig. Code info:
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                            ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint serverAuthenticationEntryPoint,
                                                            ServerAccessDeniedHandler serverAccessDeniedHandler,
                                                            ReactiveAuthenticationManager reactiveAuthenticationManager,
                                                            ServerAuthenticationConverter serverAuthenticationConverter,
                                                            ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler,
                                                            ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler,
                                                            JwtValidationWebFilter jwtValidationWebFilter) {
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter =
                authenticationWebFilter(
                        reactiveAuthenticationManager,
                        serverAuthenticationConverter,
                        successHandler,
                        failureHandler);

        SecurityWebFilterChain chain = http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
                .authenticationManager(reactiveAuthenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .logout(ServerHttpSecurity.LogoutSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                        .pathMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("/api/sys-user/**").hasAnyAuthority("PERM_ABC")
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(jwtValidationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec -> exceptionHandlingSpec
                        .accessDeniedHandler(serverAccessDeniedHandler)
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(serverAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                )
                .build();
        return chain;
    }

Now please ignore my authentication filter, because what I need to verify is permissions. When I directly access the interface through token, I deliberately reduce the user's permission to verify that the permission filter is effective.
But during the test, I encountered an exception：
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: Not Authenticated
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.commenceAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationWebFilter.java:96) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    Suppressed: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$0(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoError] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.error(Mono.java:299)
    org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$0(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53)


Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
.....

I try to finding code causing position. I found the throw position of the core：
enter image description here
My original intention was to let the exception normally enter the exception handling of the flatMap, but I don't know why I ran into the switchIfEmpty strangely.
chain.filter(exchange)
            .onErrorResume(AccessDeniedException.class, (denied) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                .filter((principal) -> (!(principal instanceof Authentication) || (principal instanceof Authentication
                        && (this.authenticationTrustResolver.isAuthenticated((Authentication) principal)))))
                .switchIfEmpty(commenceAuthentication(exchange,
                        new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                                "Full authentication is required to access this resource")))
                .flatMap((principal) -> this.accessDeniedHandler.handle(exchange, denied))
                .then());

Is my context setting problem?
Context context = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication) ;
return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(context) ;


first of all handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended and there is a reason to why there is no such filter in spring security so why are you building an insecure authentication?

Your answer caused me to think. My current process is to give JWT to the browser, then he will store JWT in the localStorage, and then directly put JWT into Header when requesting, but as you said, this is not safe, and I am going to change to the form of session id exchange.

@Toerktumlare In your opinion, what would be the right way to proceed?

by reading the spring security docs and picking one of the authentication methods there that fits your need and requirements and not invent something homemade.

@Toerktumlare The JWT must be stored securely in the client (browser, native app, service etc.) without third parties being able to access it. And it is not Spring's job to worry about how the client handles a JWT.

have i ever said its Springs responsibility? I wrote handing out JWTs to browsers (meaning public clients) is not recommended https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/ i have not said its springs responsibility? please point out where i wrote that. If this application is only verifying JWTs for example in a server to server scenario, the filter is still not needed as the verification of JWTs already exists in spring security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html so i do not see your point of your comment.

I found the problem, this is, I configured a CustomServerAuthenticationEntryPoint in my configuration，content is:
@Component
public class CustomServerAuthenticationEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final String WWW_AUTHENTICATE = "WWW-Authenticate";

    private static final String DEFAULT_REALM = "Realm";

    private static String WWW_AUTHENTICATE_FORMAT = "Basic realm=\"%s\"";

    private String headerValue = createHeaderValue(DEFAULT_REALM);

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> commence(ServerWebExchange exchange, AuthenticationException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the realm to be used
     * @param realm the realm. Default is "Realm"
     */
    public void setRealm(String realm) {
        this.headerValue = createHeaderValue(realm);
    }

    private static String createHeaderValue(String realm) {
        Assert.notNull(realm, "realm cannot be null");
        return String.format(WWW_AUTHENTICATE_FORMAT, realm);
    }
}


My initial understanding was that the exception would be sent directly to my  CustomAccessDeniedHandler， At the same time here I also posted CustomAccessDeniedHandler code:
@Component
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements ServerAccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, AccessDeniedException denied) {
      
        LogUtils.error("Denied: ", denied);
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        return response.writeWith(Mono.empty());
    }
}

However, I found that my understanding is completely stupid. The spring-security framework will handle entrypoint anyway, but this does not affect the execution of the entire exception chain. So throw e is broke my chain of execution. I am also to blame for not describing the problem clearly.
I hope to bring some ideas to others when using this framework....
